# Renumbering a summary section field starting from "1" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures, varchar

I have the following input table. I need a smart way to dynamically renumber the parents section indexes starting from "01" and show them in a new column.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express SP2

**MyTable**:

```
ID      Integer
SECTION Varchar
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Results:

```
+--+--------+
|ID|SECTION |
+--+--------+
|1 |03      |
|2 |03.01   |
|3 |03.01.01|
|4 |03.02   |
|5 |03.03   |
|6 |04      |
|7 |04.01   |
|8 |04.02   |
|9 |05      |
+--+--------+
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve from my select or procedure:

```
+--+--------+--------+
|ID|SECTION |NEWSECT |
+--+--------+--------+
|1 |03      |01      |
|2 |03.01   |01.01   |
|3 |03.01.01|01.01.01|
|4 |03.02   |01.02   |
|5 |03.03   |01.03   |
|6 |04      |02      |
|7 |04.01   |02.01   |
|8 |04.02   |02.02   |
|9 |05      |03      |
+--+--------+--------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How many root directory will be there? like... 01..02..09... More?

Comment: I was trying with a stored procedure looping through reports and storing the current value in a temporary variable, but I really don't know if it's the right way to do this. Root directories are undefined.

Comment: Also please mentioned the SQL Server Version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just string operations:

```
select t.*,
       stuff(section, 1, 2,
             right(concat('00', dense_rank() over (order by left(section, 2))), 2)
            )
from t;
```

I mean, the `dense_rank()` is doing the work for renumbering the main sections.  The rest is just getting the value into your `section`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=057a2f33f241dfd1cb28c626e248420f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Will it also work if the section start with 3 digit first and a dot. like 101.02.02?

Comment: @mkRabbani . . . No, but that was not the question that the OP asked.  If that is an issue, this can be easily adjusted or you (or the OP) could ask another question.